# React Native ImageBackground in FlatList header

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am testing my app on android and I have seen that when I scroll down and then to the top of my flatlist, the header (which have an ImageBackground component) is blank (it seems that dissapears when it is not visible in the screen) and then fades in. I don't have this error on iOS, only in android.

Here is the code of the FlatList:

```
     <FlatList
        ref={scrollRef}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={isRefreshing}
            colors={[
              colors.primary,
              colors.pink,
              colors.strawberry,
              colors.pig,
            ]}
            tintColor={colors.primary}
            onRefresh={handleRefresh}
          />
        }
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <Header
              uploadProgress={uploadProgress}
              onConfigurationButtonPress={handleConfigurationDisplay}
            />
          </View>
        }
        ListFooterComponent={<Tab />}
        style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.white }]}
      />
```

As you can see, in my flatlist I have two components, a tab in the footer, and a custom component called Header, which code is:

```
   ...
   <ImageBackground
      source={{ uri }}
      blurRadius={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 40 : 10}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View
        style={[styles.overlay, { backgroundColor: colors.transparentWhite }]}
      />
      {children}
    </ImageBackground>
   ...

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
      },
     overlay: {
       ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
     },
   });
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure if this is the case but in my experience I would say the problem is the fact that your ImageBackground is with flex instead of a defined "size". Try defining a size like width: 100% and height 200 for example.

Besides that I normally send a function that returns a component to ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I also tried this but didn't work. It is a strange behaviour of the ImageBackground component, it fades out the image when I scroll down

Comment: What about instead of using ImageBackground, use a View and an Image with position absolute, width 100% and height 100%?

Comment: Yes. I am gonna do this.